# Center Float with ::before and ::after elements

Tags: css, css-float

I want to center an H3 with his elements after and before, for the moment i have this :

HTML

```
<h2>Nos réalisations dans la région</h2>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
}
h2::before {
    content: '';
    width: 60px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #248290;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 0;
}
h2::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #248290;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 0;
}
```

I want to center all element like the photo.

[image: ![For the moment]

[image: I want it.]

Comment: Can you clarify what you want exactly? Two screenshots with different content, and three different font weights, is confusing if you don't explain more. Also, the HTML and CSS need to be more complete; we need to see what happens now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution. There are more but this is very simple. Positioning left to 50% and subtract the half of the element width using negative margin.

```css
h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    background: #333;
}
h2::before {
    content: '';
    width: 60px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #248290;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-30px;
}
h2::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #248290;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Nos réalisations dans la région</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's perfect. :)